# Detect if boost test case failed

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'd like to log some more data on BOOST's assertion failure. Not sure if this is possible and how.

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( TestCase1 )
{
    Data d;

    d.fillUp(...);

    d.operation1(...);
    BOOST_CHECK(d == ...);

    d.operation2(...);
    BOOST_CHECK(d == ...);

    ...

    if( /* anything above failed */)
    {
        log << d;
    }
}
```

I am having problem with the last condition. Can you advise? I'd like the error log to indicate what were the conditions in the Data object when assertions happened. Ideally i would like them to be dumped once, even if multiple assertions in the testcase happened.

Comment: Exactly trying to do the same in a project.

Comment: I did not find any solution ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm am doing the following to accomplish what you want:

```
BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE( current_test_passing(), d);
```

using the following function that I have just added to my collection of test helper functions:

```
#include <boost/test/results_collector.hpp>

inline bool current_test_passing()
{
  using namespace boost::unit_test;
  test_case::id_t id = framework::current_test_case().p_id;
  test_results rez = results_collector.results(id);
  return rez.passed();
}
```

I'm finding is useful for loops in combination with BOOST_REQUIRE_… so I can quickly see for which particular iteration any of many checks are failing without having to add the "i=" message to every check:

```
for (int i=0; i < HUGE_NUMBER; ++i) {
  … many checks …
  BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE( current_test_passing(), "FAILED i=" << i );
}
```